# Creating Svelte Web Components in Parent Directory

Tags: svelte, rollupjs, svelte-3

I am trying to build web components using svelte.  Everything works fine if I go with the default file structure, but in my particular project I have a need to rework the file to move the `src` file to a higher level directory.  In other words, here is the normal file structure that works fine:

```
dev
  - dist
  - src
    - Component.svelte
    - index.js
  package.json
  rollup.config.js
index.html
```

And here is the setup I need:

```
dev
  - dist
src
  - Component.svelte
  - index.js
  package.json
  rollup.config.js
index.html
```

Note that I have moved the `src` folder up one level.  At the same time, I updated the  `rolup.config.js` files as follows:

```
export default {
  input: '../src/index.js',
  output: [
    { file: pkg.module, format: 'es' },
    { file: pkg.main, format: 'umd', name },
  ],
  plugins: [svelte({ customElement: true }), resolve()],
}
```

Note `input: '../src/index.js'`.

The problem is, when I run this it does not work.  At the same time, the messages I received when I run `npm run build` are significantly different.  Here is the output when I use the standard file structure:

```
> SvelteComponent@ build C:\laragon\www\svelte3\dev
> rollup -c


src/index.js → dist/index.mjs, dist/index.js...
created dist/index.mjs, dist/index.js in 188ms
```

And here is the output with the modified file structure:

```
> SvelteComponent@ build C:\laragon\www\svelte3\dev
> rollup -c


../src/index.js → dist/index.mjs, dist/index.js...
(!) Unresolved dependencies
https://rollupjs.org/guide/en/#warning-treating-module-as-external-dependency
svelte/internal (imported by ..\src\Component.svelte)
(!) Missing global variable name
Use output.globals to specify browser global variable names corresponding to external modules
svelte/internal (guessing 'internal')
created dist/index.mjs, dist/index.js in 81ms
```

Note that extra messages:

```
(!) Unresolved dependencies
https://rollupjs.org/guide/en/#warning-treating-module-as-external-dependency
svelte/internal (imported by ..\src\Component.svelte)
(!) Missing global variable name
Use output.globals to specify browser global variable names corresponding to external modules
svelte/internal (guessing 'internal')
```

So, with that said, what do I have to do to get this to work properly?  I appreciate any help you can offer.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Rollup's `input` field isn't relative to the config file, it's relative to the current working directory. Just use `src/index.js`

Comment: Thanks for answering my question (and for Rollup/Svelte/Sapper).  I'm not following your answer, though.  Are you suggesting that I give up on trying to rework the directory structure that I need?  Also, what do you mean by 'relative to the working directory'.  In my example, what is the working directory.

Comment: You can use whatever directory structure you want. By 'working directory' I just mean the directory that you're in *when you run Rollup*, which needn't be the same as the directory containing the config file

Comment: Okay, I'm confused -- because right now the config file is in the working directory, but when I run `npm run build` it does not work properly (as noted in my question above).  As such, the path to the `input` filed is correct -- but it does not seem to work because it is in a directory that is **above** the root directory of rollup.  Any ideas?